# Is there a way for Android Chrome to remember Geolocation permission for my page?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, geolocation

I'm working on a web app that requires the user's location to get weather data. It's critical for the purpose of the app, and the location call has to be made basically every time the app is used.

It works fine on Chrome on desktop, but when I try to use my site on Android Chrome it asks for the location permission every time. Is there a way to use the Geolocation API that will remember the permission and not make the user approve it every time?

This is how I'm calling the API, as inline javascript on the page that uses the coordinates.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCoords);
function setCoords(position) {
    // Do stuff to the page
}
```

Comment: If there's not a way to remember the permission, is my best approach to make a native android app?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out this was happening in a web view when I opened the page from a Facebook message. It remembers the location permission on Android Chrome.